# Time required to read presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

There are around 500 slides, the first slide is an introduction, second slide is for instructions with the action button for the Start_time macro - once clicked the timer starts. Slides 3 - 499 have one word in each, so the reader will have to go through each of the slide in a period of time, that's why the word_count equals slide.count minus three. The last slide will have the action button that when clicked will show the reading evaluation.

This macro is for my PowerPoint presentation intended to give a reading evaluation to my students.

```
Dim Start_time As Date
_______________________________________________________________________________________
Sub Start_time()
'at action button click in the first slide the time starts counting
Start_time = Now()

End Sub
_______________________________________________________________________________________

Sub ReadingTime()
'at action button click on the last slide the evaluaton message appears
Dim Reading_Time As String
Dim End_Time As Date
Dim iTotal_time As Long
Dim Word_count As Integer


End_Time = Now()
iTotal_time = DateDiff("d", End_Time, Start_time)
Word_count = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count - 3
Reading_Time = Word_count / iTotal_time * 24 * 60


MsgBox "Evaluation : Your reading speed is " & Reading_Time & "words per minute"

End Sub
```

Comment: you didn't clarify what is going wrong with your macro... please do it to get accurate support.

Comment: hello KazJaw, this is already an updated code thanks to the help of Bathsheba. The macro code seems functioning but not accurately. I tried to run the presentation in different paces but the evaluation result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean end_time = now()?!!!

Another deeper issue is you probably want to declare start_time at the top of the module as it will go out if scope (I.e. will no longer be available) once the start_time sub exits: type
 dim start_time 
right at the top of the module to do this.

Try this:

```
Dim m_start_time As Date 'renamed this as it clashes with a function name

Public Sub Start_time()
    'at action button click in the first slide the time starts counting
    m_start_time = Now()

End Sub


Public Sub ReadingTime()
    'at action button click on the last slide the evaluaton message appears
    Dim Reading_Time As String
    Dim End_Time As Date
    Dim iTotal_time As Double   'use a double as fraction days are important
    Dim Word_count As Integer


    End_Time = Now()
    iTotal_time = End_Time - m_start_time
    Word_count = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count - 3
    Reading_Time = Word_count / iTotal_time * 24 * 60


    MsgBox "Evaluation : Your reading speed is " & Reading_Time & "words per minute"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Bathsheba, thank you for the suggestion. I will try it now. What about the iReading_Time = tWords / tTime / 60? It say "zero results". I was wondrin if there is some kind of formula for the conversion. I want the result to be in words per minute.

Comment: Time will be measured in days. So need to multiply by 24 x 60 to get minutes. Your time is zero because of all the problems I mentioned above ;-)

Comment: I did so as you suggested. As I run the code it says "compile error: ambiguous name detected : start_time"

Comment: Please re-edit your question with the amended code and I'll take another look.

Comment: My presentation is like this: There are around 500 slides in the presentation, the first slide is an introduction, second slide is for instructions with the action button for the Start_time macro - once clicked the timer starts. Slides 3 - 499 has one word in each, so he reader will have to go through each of the slide in a period of time, that's why the word_count equals slide.count minus three. The last slide will have the action button that is when clicked will show the reading evaluation.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a macro. I didn't check ActivePresentation.Slides.Count - 3; you need to check if that is the word count: I suspect it's the number of slides less 3.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for that. I edited my macro as you said and it worked. It gave me reading evaluation, but there's a mistake I think. I tried the presentation myself and read the words in a different pace but I got the same evaluation whether I read(scan through the slides) it faster or slower.

Comment: Two things: 1) I think your definition of Word_count is incorrect as I think it counts the number of slides 2) Try debugging the starting time with a MsgBox m_start_time call in the ReadingTime sub.

Comment: Hello, I tried to change the Word_count formula to "500 - 3" and it still gives the same result. I think the problem now is with the m_Start_time. I tried your suggestion about the MsgBox m_start_time call but got continuous errors. I wrote - MsgBox (m_Start_time (Call)) and resulted in error.

Comment: hello Bathsheba, thank you so much for helping me with my code. with your suggestions I've managed to finally make the code function well.